# Trying to modify /system/build.prop we are getting Permission denied

Tags: android, bash, sed, adb

After running from Termux this:

```
$ adb shell su 0 "mount -o rw,remount /"
$ adb shell su 0 "echo net.hostname=XXXXXX >> /system/build.prop"
```

we are getting

`/system/bin/sh: can't create /system/build.prop: Permission denied`

We don't get any error when running this below, so the line `net.hostname=XXXXXXXX` is added to the end of `/system/build.prop`

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /
echo "net.hostname=XXXXXXXX" >> /system/build.prop
```

Permisions of `/system/build.prop`

`-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  1.9K 2023-10-02 20:23 build.prop`

```
$ mount
/dev/root on / type ext4 (ro,relatime,seclabel,block_validity,delalloc,barrier,user_xattr,acl)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,size=1027020k,nr_inodes=185830,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,seclabel,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)
none on /dev/stune type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,schedtune)
none on /dev/cpuctl type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
none on /dev/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,noprefix,release_agent=/sbin/cpuset_release_agent)
cg2_bpf on /dev/cg2_bpf type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
adb on /dev/usb-ffs/adb type functionfs (rw,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
/sys/kernel/debug on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
tmpfs on /mnt type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/block/param on /mnt/vendor/param type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,seclabel,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/block/tee on /mnt/vendor/tee type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,seclabel,nodelalloc,errors=panic,data=ordered)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/default/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/read/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=23,derive_gid,default_normal)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/write/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal)
/dev/block/odm on /odm type ext4 (ro,relatime,seclabel,block_validity,delalloc,barrier,user_xattr,acl,inode_readahead_blks=8)
/dev/block/product on /product type ext4 (ro,relatime,seclabel,block_validity,delalloc,barrier,user_xattr,acl,inode_readahead_blks=8)
/dev/block/vendor on /vendor type ext4 (ro,relatime,seclabel,block_validity,delalloc,barrier,user_xattr,acl,inode_readahead_blks=8)
none on /acct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct)
none on /config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/block/data on /data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,seclabel,nodelalloc,resgid=1065,errors=panic,data=ordered)
/dev/block/cache on /cache type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,seclabel,nodelalloc,errors=panic,data=ordered)
/dev/block/metadata on /metadata type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,seclabel,nodelalloc,errors=panic,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /storage type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755,gid=1000)
/data/media on /storage/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal)
tmpfs on /storage/self type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755,gid=1000)
```

Android 9

**EDIT:** now we don't get permissions error when using `sed` instead to add the line at the end of the file:

`$ adb shell su 0 "sed -i '$aNew line of data' /system/build.prop"`

but the problem now is that we get the string `ne of data` below every line in the file, instead of just `New line of data` at the end of the file.

Comment: [GNU sed requires whitespace after the a](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands) ... and you're probably losing the `$` which would mean "last line" in the expansion done by your interpretive shell.  Or somewhere else along the line.

Answer (score 1):

Your sed command is inside double quotes which means the `'`s around your sed script are just literal chars, not delimiters, which means `$aNew` will be expanded by the shell as a variable so you're really executing `sed ' li...'` and that `i` is being treated as the sed `insert` instruction thereby inserting "ne of data" throughout your file. Try puting a `\` before the `$`, e.g. using `bash -c` in place of your `adb ...` which I don't have:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
```

```
$ sed '$aNew line' file
1
2
3
New line
```

```
$ bash -c "sed '$aNew line' file"
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command
```

```
$ bash -c "sed '\$aNew line' file"
1
2
3
New line
```

or:

```
$ bash -c 'sed "\$aNew line" file'
1
2
3
New line
```

That doesn't explain why you aren't seeing the error message I show above so also check if your version of sed requires an extension after the `-i`, e.g. as BSD does as that can also have some unexpected effects when you don't provide that extension as then sed thinks at least part of your script is an extension.